# Reset or clear all selection of a widget property when it become invisible

Tags: properties, widget, kentico

In my widget I am making some properties of the widget visible or non visible according to user selection. For example I have a property X which have some check boxes and will only be visible on a certain condition. If I have selected a property Y that should make property X visible and I selected one check box from property X. It fine till now but if I un select that property Y this make property X invisible, but the check box from property X remains checked. How do I make all selection clear when Property X is invisible ?

I am using Kentico 10

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue before and I don't believe it is possible.

My solution is to wrap Property X (in my transformation or web part code where this value is displayed) with an if statement based on the value of Property Y (which is a boolean in this case).

In a Text/XML transformation, this would look like:

```
{% if (ToBool(PropertyY, false)) %}
  <div>{% PropertyX %}</div>
{% } else { %}
    <!-- Don't use property X's value -->
{% } #%}
```

In a custom web part code behind file:

```
if (ValidationHelper.GetBoolean(GetValue("PropertyY"), false))
{
    // Property Y is true
    // use Property X's value here
}
else
{
    // Property Y is false
    // Don't use Property X's value here
}
```